# Error " Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" " of selenium with Robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have a Selenium Python test suite. It starts to run show error msg.

> unexpected error: Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no
>   attribute 'process'" in del of
>   selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x040F20B0
>   ignored

and

> Warning [ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on
>   failure: No browser is open

How can I fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error for you is **"WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"**

Download Chrome driver from 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Then set the path to chrome driver

```
*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
*** Keywords ****
Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ${PATHTODRIVER}/chromedriver.exe
```